# Debugging JavaScript with asynchronous functions in third-party libraries?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with https://github.com/sameer-shelavale/blitz-gmap-editor ; the file `test5.html` there allows you to place a marker, and when you click on it, you get a form to edit its properties:

[image: blitz-gmaps]

I've started by adding some extra buttons, that add markers with pre-populated data. Then, I click on them so the form is shown, I edit nothing in the form, and press Cancel. Approx half a second to a second after this, I get in browser console:

```
TypeError: a.url.substr is not a function  util.js:202:114
```

I would very much like to get rid of this error (note it doesn't occur in the original `test5.html`).

The problem is - first I have no idea what this function is or does; I found [Do we have a Uncompressed javascript Library for Google Maps API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931939/do-we-have-a-uncompressed-javascript-library-for-google-maps-api-v3):

> There is no uncompressed library. All the API methods are accessed according to the published documentation, so there doesn't need to be an uncompressed version.

Yeah, right - absolutely no need for that, sure! Surely it is not Google keeping a leash on their properties - it's just that nobody would ever need to know what is going on, as it would be impossible to ever get into a problem that bad `:)`

Anyways, the stack traces that Firefox spits out are:

```
rz.prototype.load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/17/util.js:202:114
qz.prototype.load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/17/util.js:201:427
_.yz.prototype.load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/17/util.js:204:224
dz.prototype.load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/17/util.js:200:287
cz.prototype.load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/17/util.js:199:133
SS http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/17/marker.js:5:217
WS http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/17/marker.js:7:482
XS http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/17/marker.js:7:116
VS.prototype.Y http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/17/marker.js:35:646
_.zf.prototype.L/a.F< http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js:112:4221
```

... and Chromium outputs this:

```
util.js:202 Uncaught TypeError: a.url.substr is not a function
rz.load @   util.js:202
cz.load @   util.js:199
oz  @   util.js:6
lz  @   util.js:6
kz.load @   util.js:201
qz.load @   util.js:201
_.yz.load   @   util.js:204
dz.load @   util.js:200
cz.load @   util.js:199
SS  @   marker.js:5
WS  @   marker.js:7
XS  @   marker.js:7
VS.Y    @   marker.js:35
(anonymous function)    @   js?v=3.26&libraries=drawing,geometry:112
```

So, apparently the error occurs in `rz.prototype.load`, and is being initiated by `_.zf.prototype.L/a.F<` that is `(anonymous function)`; from the Firefox info (...maps/api/js:112:4221), I extracted this for `_.zf.prototype...`:

```
...
_.zf.prototype.L=function(){
  var a=this;
  a.F||(
        a.F=window.setTimeout(
          function(){
            a.F=void 0; // <=== column:4221 here at ;
            a.Y()
          }
          ,a.ql)
       )
};
...
```

and this for `rz.prototype` (which contains `util.js:202:114`):

```
...
rz.prototype.load=function(a,b){
  var c=this.la;
  this.b&&"data:"!=a.url.substr(0,5)||(a=new _.ez(a.url)); // column 114 is right before a.url.substr..
  return c.load(a,function(d){
    !d&&_.m(a.crossOrigin)?c.load(new _.ez(a.url),b):b(d)
  })
};
...
```

So, the caller `_.zf.prototype.L` function does a `setTimeout` which eventually calls `rz.prototype`, which explains why this error is shown only after some time has expired after I press "Cancel".

But my question is - what is it in the rest of the code, which might call this `_.zf.prototype.L` function? How can I find that? If `_.zf.prototype.L` itself was called through a `setTimeout`, would it have "remembered" the originating caller/call stack, and can that be retrieved for debugging? Or, would it be possible to set a breakpoint, which breaks whenever a function with a name `_.zf.prototype.L` is about to be called?

I tried looking into [How to view JavaScript function calls as they occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671794/how-to-view-javascript-function-calls-as-they-occur) (which has no info on how to do a function call trace); and then found https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/a-tracer-utility-in-2kb/ - using this library, I can do:

```
tracer.traceAll(BlitzMap,true); 
tracer.traceAll(BlitzMap.getMapObj(),true);
```

.... but then it traces the object functions OK, the map obj is a bit weird (there's like 3000+ `tracing traceOff` messages in the console while the page loads) although it seems to trace some parts too - however, when I do my test case, after pressing "Cancel" all I get are my code traces (which do not crash), and then a second goes by, and I get the error/stacktraces above without any other trace.

So, how to debug a problem like this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to get somewhere with this problem - even if the close vote claims the problem is "too broad".

First, if the "front-facing" javascript from the API is:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.26&libraries=drawing,geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

... then download it to a file:

```
wget "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.26&libraries=drawing,geometry" -O gmapsapi.js
```

... and use this file in your HTML instead of the online one:

```
<script src="gmapsapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then open your HTML file in Firefox, have it run, and then do in Firefox: File / Save Page As / Web page, complete.

This will download additional scripts like `util.js` and such locally in the saved page folder.

Now, open the saved (as Web page, complete) version of the HTML file - it should have also replaced the online links to scripts to the downloaded local ones.

Then, open `gmapsapi.js` from the saved folder, and introduce linebreaks to `_.zf.prototype.L` function:

```
_.zf.prototype.L=function(){
  var a=this;
  a.F||(a.F=window.setTimeout(function(){a.F=void 0;a.Y()},a.ql))
};
```

... to be able to set up a breakpoint on a line later.

Now, open the saved HTML file in Firefox, open Firebug, in the Script tab find `gmapsapi.js`, and set a breakpoint on the `var a=this;` line.

Now run the stuff - in my case, doing all up to and including pressing Cancel - and the JS engine will break; then you can do `console.trace()` in Firebug console, and obtain this kind of a trace (after which the error occurs):

```
_.zf.prototype.L()                            gmapsapi.js (line 114)
VS.prototype.changed(a="modelIcon")           marker.js (line 35)
Bb(a=Object { type="object"}, b="modelIcon")  gmapsapi.js (line 37)
Bb(a=Object { type="object"}, b="icon")       gmapsapi.js (line 37)
_.k.set(a="icon", b=Object { type="object"})  gmapsapi.js (line 96)
_.vc/<(c=Object { type="object"})             gmapsapi.js (line 47)
_.k.setValues()                               gmapsapi.js (line 97)
a = Object { type="object"}
BlitzMap</this.updateOverlay()                blitz.js (line 545)
BlitzMap</this.closeInfoWindow()              blitz.js (line 514)
onclick()input[3] onclick (line 1)
event = Object { type="object"}
```

... and indeed - this pointed out where the bug is: namely, I had hacked `blitz.js` and ended up writing an empty string `""` for the icon of a marker, which ended up being the cause of the error.

This stack trace reveals one more thing - and that is, why does this error occur only the first time I press cancel, and not subsequent times; well, the answer is, the erring code runs only when `VS.prototype.changed(a="modelIcon")`, so the second time, the setting of empty string is not a "change" anymore, so no error then.